# Can I use a data-attribute as the href attribute value for an anchor?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I am working with the following code:

```
<div data-q_id="#strategy" class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid">
[...]
</div>
```

Is there anyway I can use the `data-q_id` attribute as an achor for a link on the same page?

I would like to be able to do this:

`<a href="[data attribute referenced here]">lorem ipsum</a>`

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0sox9ej0/1/

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to modify an anchor in the DOM? Do you want the anchor built with a certain `href` attribute value by your server-side app? Please clarify.

Comment: I was looking to use the `data-q_id` attribute as an anchor in the same way that's common to use the `id` attribute as an anchor for an `<a>` element. It looks like the HTML spec does not allow for this possibility though. I'm already aware of how to achieve this with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there are many divs with many anchors, but in the case it is just one, this works:

```
$("a:first").attr("href", $("div:first").data("q_id"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbp3fvq8/

If there are more divs/anchors, and there is some logic as to how they are related, please update your question.

Comment: so it looks like there is no HTML only solution then?

Comment: You cannot modify the DOM with just HTML, you need Javascript. Unless I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: I was looking to use the `data-q_id` attribute as an anchor like the `id` attribute, but I understand now that the HTML spec does not allow for this, which I suppose makes sense since the data attribute I've provided is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: added working jsfiddle

with `jQuery` you can use the attribute selector .

for your example that would be:

`$('[data-q_id="#strategy"]').something...`

or without short jquery version

`jQuery('[data-q_id="#strategy"]').something...`

and then you could just say something like

```
$('[data-q_id="#strategy"]').attr('id', $('[data-q_id="#strategy"]').attr('data-q_id').substring(1));
```

`substring(1)` to get rid of the `#` because im not quite sure if it could cause problems

http://jsfiddle.net/u6c4mo3j/